# WebView getting created multiple times (on each link click)

Tags: android, webview

I initialize a WebView object in my activity, load the URL and if the URL loaded correctly, I start another activity that sets this web view as its content view.

Code where WebView is constructed:

```
webView = new MyWebView( getApplicationContext(), Settings.this, AsyncWebConnect.this);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Once the web view has loaded the URL (I get this info through a callback), I initialize the second activity which will show the web view.

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).setWebView(webView);
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebActivity.class));
```

And in the WebActivity's onCreate, I retrieve this web view and set it as content:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final WebView engine = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getWebView();
    setContentView(engine);
}
```

The problem is, each time I click on a link within the loaded page, the activity is created again. Has someone see this earlier? Please let know if there's something wrong that's been done here.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. When you add an existing view to another activity it recreates it. At least that's how I always thought it works.

Comment: I had to move the webview and its initialization in the activity that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to intercept the page loads like in this [example](http://lexandera.com/tag/webviewclient/)